# filter values of a list in R

Tags: r

I have this list of data-frames,

```
[[1]]
  ns                  title missing
1  0 another string to fail        

[[2]]
  pageid ns  title
1  40657  0 Action

[[3]]
  pageid ns        title
1   8609  0 Nationalisme
```

I would like to have a script to remove all ranks that don't have "pageid", "ns" ans "title" as colnames.

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `%in%` and `all` to create a logical `vector` by looping through the `list` elements with `sapply`.  The logical `vector` can be used to subset the `list`.

```
lst[sapply(lst, function(x) all(c("pageid", "ns", "title") %in% names(x)))]
#[[1]]
#  pageid ns  title
#1  40657  0 Action

#[[2]]
#  pageid ns        title
#1   8609  0 Nationalisme
```

---

Or we can use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) all(c("pageid", "ns", "title") %in% names(x)), lst)
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(data.frame(ns = 0, title = "another string", missing = "to fail"), 
        data.frame(pageid = 40657, ns =0, title = "Action"), 
        data.frame(pageid= 8609, ns=0, title = "Nationalisme"))
```